# Convert UIKit coordinates to Quartz/CoreImage (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, core-image, quartz

Is there a way of converting UIKit coordinates (0,0 top left) to Quartz/CoreImage (0,0 bottom left)? Can't find anything swift related like this on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use affine transformation matrix, this snipped is taken from a code of mine to convert from Core Image / Core graphics to UIKit:

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t,0, -imageView.bounds.size.height);
```

Basically you need to:

- Negate the y axis
- translate origin by the view height

After the you can use those geometric functions to calculate your rect or points

```
CGPoint pointUIKit = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pointCI, t);
CGRect rectUIKit = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rectCI, t);
```

In Swift 3.x:

```
var t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
t = t.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -imageView.bounds.size.height)
let pointUIKit = pointCI.applying(t)
let rectUIKIT = rectCI.applying(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the origin in the *bottom left* versus the *top left*, you need to do nothing with the X axis, but you need to flip the right axis. UIKit (or in this case, Core Graphics) uses CGPoints. Core Image typically uses a CIVectors, which can have 2, 3, or 4 axis angles.

Here's a simple function that will turn a CGPoint(X,Y) into a CIVector(X,Y):

```
func createVector(_ point:CGPoint, image:CIImage) -> CIVector {
    return CIVector(x: point.x, y: image.extent.height - point.y)
}
```

Comment: Yes, as dfd says. The only difference between the coordinate values is the view's height in the y axis.